# Graphics3D evaluation not completing

Tags: graphics

I have a list of cuboid centers, and I want to plot them. I am using the following code, but the evaluation never completes. How can I get it to work?

```
dx = 2.5;
dy = 2.5;
dz = 2.5;

Graphics3D[{Red, EdgeForm[], Opacity[.4], 
  Cuboid[# - {dx, dy, dz}/2, # + {dx, dy, dz}/2]& /@ listVoxel}]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that something is not right on your side, or I misunderstand your problem. When I try to execute the following with 10,000 objects, it seems to work fine:

```
dx = 2.5; dy = 2.5; dz = 2.5;
listVoxel = RandomInteger[{-250, 250}, {10000, 3}];

(plot = Graphics3D[
    {Red, Opacity[.4], EdgeForm[None], 
     Cuboid[# - {dx, dy, dz}/2, # + {dx, dy, dz}/2] & /@ listVoxel}
   ];) // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out: {0.0905875, Null} *)

plot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is the same if I consider more closely spaced cuboids with heavy overlaps:

```
listVoxel2 = RandomInteger[{-15, 15}, {3000, 3}];

(plot2 =
    Graphics3D[
     {Red, Opacity[.4], EdgeForm[None], 
      Cuboid[# - {dx, dy, dz}/2, # + {dx, dy, dz}/2] & /@ listVoxel2}
     ];) // AbsoluteTiming

plot2

(* Out: {0.0341774, Null} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Upvote because I like the second picture :-)